# How to simulate Google login using gaeunit

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps, google-signin, gaeunit

I am currently using gaeunit to perform automated test on my google app engine application. I am wondering whether it's possible to simulate the user login action using his/her google account using gaeunit?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Two situations:

1. Local Dev server: login is mocked via a simple web form. You can do a http POST to log in.
2. Production server: login goes through the Google auth infrastructure. No way to mock this. To make this work you'd need to code around it.

Answer (score 0):

The dev server login is emulated just by setting environment variables.  You can fake a login with three lines of python to set the three env variables, then the User API will behave as if you're logged in.

http://eatdev.tumblr.com/post/13070970245/faking-gae-user-authentication-locally-for-django